# laravel test blade @extends mocking

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit

I want to test a function that returns a view but is running an error because it trying to extend a blade. How can I mock @extends function?

search.blade.php:

```
@extends('main')

@section('main-content')

   <h1 class="py-4">Title</h1>
   more code....

@endsection
```

I try this:

```
View::shouldReceive('make')
            ->with('main');
```

not working, get this error:
`No matching handler found for Mockery_2_Illuminate_View_Factory::make('search.search', [], []). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method`

Comment: It is saying that your `with` is not correct. You are passing `->with('main')` when in reality it should be `->with('search.search', [], [])`, or you should be able to do `View::partialMock()->shouldReceive(...)->...`